# Sharepoint site icon keeps reverting to old icon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Okay so I'm using sharepoint online and the site I'm developing is pretty much done. There's only one issue, the icon.

I can change the site icon to the company logo with ease, but seemingly at random it just switches back to the previous icon. I've had a look in the site assets folder and it turns out every time it happens the previous logo is re-added to the folder and set as the site icon automatically.

I have no idea why this is happening and need to fix it quickly as it is the last issue.

Maybe it's an easy fix? May be something to do with the group that it's attached to? Maybe there's a way to overwrite it using CSS?

Any tips or advice?

Comment: Add screenshot, not undestand ((

Comment: I change the icon and it just randomly reverts back to the old icon created by the previous developer for the site. There's nothing to screenshot really it's just an icon change. I just don't understand as to why it is automatically reverting.

Comment: You change icon to this url - _layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx??? Add your logotype in RootSitesCollection in library SiteAssets and dont remember that there should be read access to this library for all users.

Comment: Okay I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue.
The logo was synced with the office 365 group that the sharepoint site was linked to.
I went into Outlook and deleted the group photo, then changed the site logo again and it hasn't changed since.